# Promise.all of array of Promises created with fill only executed just once

Tags: node.js, promise, axios

Im facing a really strange error. Im calling the same endpoint multiple times so I can test the performance of my app. When I do the following test:

```
const call = () => axios.post('http://localhost:3000');

(async () => {
  let calls = [call(), call(), call(), call(), call()]
  let responses = await Promise.all(calls);
})();
```

I get the following log at server:

```
POST / 200 2576.633 ms - 18
POST / 200 2587.848 ms - 18
POST / 200 2596.250 ms - 18
POST / 200 2583.056 ms - 18
POST / 200 3190.753 ms - 18
```

Everything is right! :)

**But** if I create the array dynamically like this:

```
const call = () => axios.post('http://localhost:3000');

(async () => {
  let calls = new Array(5);
  calls = calls.fill(call());
  let responses = await Promise.all(calls);
})();
```

**The log at server is just one**:

```
POST / 200 3803.059 ms - 18
```

How is this even possible? Is it related to cache?

*Note: Both script and server are using Node 10.14.0 Server is a minimal Express App, no Nginx or other webservers running between.*

Comment: You are looking for `Array.from({length: 5}, call)` if you want `call()` to be executed five times.

Comment: @Bergi Cleaner! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a cache issue.

**Array.fill()** does not create a new object for every element. It uses the same object reference.

```js
function call(){ return new Promise(()=>{})}

var arr1 = new Array(4);
arr1.fill(call());
var arr2 = [call(),call(),call(),call()];

console.log('arr1 =>', arr1);
console.log('arr2 =>', arr2);

console.log('arr1 compare objects arr1[0] === arr1[1] =>', arr1[0] === arr1[1]);
console.log('arr2 compare objects arr2[0] === arr2[1] =>', arr2[0] === arr2[1]);

var arr3 = new Array(4);
arr3.fill({});
arr3[0].a = 1; // update for first 
console.log('Arr3[1].a =>', arr3[1].a);
console.log('Arr3[2].a =>', arr3[2].a);
console.log('Arr3[3].a =>', arr3[3].a);
```